# Creating a list from an excel file that's a slice of a column. How can I print it without a 'text:' prefix in any value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

Trying to fetch a list of values from an excel file consisting of a column but has to end at a certain row. Can fetch it using a slice of the col and rows, however a prefix of 'text:' appears. This makes the list incompatible for what I need to use it for.

```
import xlrd
import csv


loc = ("/Users/uni/Desktop/TESTEXCEL.xls")

wb =xlrd.open_workbook(loc)

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0,0)

CANDIDATE = sheet.col_slice(colx=5,
                            start_rowx=1,
                            end_rowx=29)

print (CANDIDATE)
```

RESULT:

```
[text:u'lt102', text:u'lt103', text:u'lt104', text:u'lt105', text:u'lt108', text:u'lt124', text:u'lt149', text:u'lt151', text:u'lt152', text:u'lt153', text:u'lt195', text:u'lt223', text:u'lt229', text:u'lt254', text:u'lt255', text:u'lt268', text:u'lt269', text:u'lt270', text:u'lt277', text:u'lt278', text:u'lt280', text:u'lt284', text:u'lt285', text:u'lt287', text:u'lt299', text:u'lt95', text:u'lt96', text:u'lt97']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` library, it has convenient `read_excel` method. Here is example:

```
import pandas as pd

column_number = 5
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/uni/Desktop/TESTEXCEL.xls', usecols=[column_number], nrows=29, header=None)
values = df[column_number].to_list()  # a list of values in your 5th column
```

You can read more about `read_excel` here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html